# React-Native debugging: Failed to print error: Requiring module .... threw an exception: Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set,

Tags: android, react-native

For some strange reason, apart from the general flakiness of all things RN and android I get this error when Reloading my app.

Failed to print error:  Requiring module "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

It's a pretty basic app.js

So I create an app using npx react-native init myapp
I'm trying to learn react-native-ble-manager

Because I'm using an android device I use adb devices, then adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 (though I don't know why except it works)

I start metro from a windows command prompt (because I get errors using anything else) npx react-native start

From another command window I run npx react-native run-android

Then I press d on metro and on the device I start debug which brings up a browser window (brave) and I press F12 to bring up the console etc.

Now and again when I "Reload app" I get the following error:

Failed to print error:  Requiring module "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules.

I press Reload app again and I get back to normal

I've seen one other post that mentions something similar from 2 years ago that had no responses.

Okay maybe it's not a biggie in the scheme of things, but I'm now on a mission get rid of all errors and failings with developing React-Native apps because fundamentally there is something very wrong with the experience of developing RN apps and I'm mighty sick of it.

Do the devs at Facebook not experience such errors. How do they set up their development environment, because surely such clever folk would not put up with all this insanity.

Gordon :)

Edit: VS Code screen grabs illustrating what I see:
[image: mage of error in VS Code]

[image: VS Code when reload app clicked after error]

Answer (score 0):

### From past experience, it can happen when importing something from a wrong location - something named similar within the *node_module* packages.

In my case I was importing a constant say `Colors` from a location suggested by the intellisense in VS code from a random library from within *node_modules* - something like:

`import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/<some random RN library>'`.

Fixed it by resolving the import path.

Answer (score -3):

Try running 'npm start' in your app folder.

Comment: @gfmoore If this answer does not help you, let me know so we can explore better ways together.

Comment: Hi, tried this, but no joy. I've added a couple of screen shots from VS Code to illustrate. Btw what does npm start do that npx react-native start not do? and why did you think it would help?

Comment: this error usually means that something in your project is breaking and it's not using the proper alias for npx react-native run-android. you might want to go back to your last working version of your app and then add things back slowly until you find what package or code is causing problems.

Comment: I have no idea because it could be any number of things and it’s too hard to know from just this error.