# Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am getting he following error when running a jest test:
● Test suite failed to run

```
Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

  1 | import { Platform } from "react-native";
> 2 | import env from "react-native-config";
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | // const env = require("react-native-config").default;
  5 |

  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
  at Object.invariant (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:181:3)
  at Object.require [as NativeModules] (node_modules/react-native/index.js:386:12)
  at Object.NativeModules (node_modules/react-native-config/index.js:8:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (config.js:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/localization/I18n.js:14:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/CommonUtils.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/localDB/Config.js:18:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/trust/__tests__/unit/TrustHeading.test.js:1:1)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
```

My config files for jest, babel and typescript are as follows:

**jest.config.js**

```
/**
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
 */

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  clearMocks: true,

  collectCoverage: true,

  // A set of global variables that need to be available in all test environments
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },

  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "json"],

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/unit/*.test.js",
  ],

  transformIgnorePatterns: [],

};

module.exports = config;
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["src/*"],
      "sample-mobile/*": ["./*"],
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"]
    },
    // This flag is required to be true because of moment.js
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = params => {
  const isTest = params.env("test");
  const config = {
    presets: [
      "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
      ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current", esmodules: true } }],
    ],
    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      "remove-test-ids",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { loose: true }],
    ],
  };
  if (isTest) {
    config.plugins.push([
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods",
      {
        loose: true,
      },
    ]);
  }
  return config;
};
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer": "^3.0.4",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.x",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@realm/react": "^0.4.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.10.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.10",
    "appcenter-cli": "^2.14.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.33",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "camelcase-keys": "^6.2.1",
    "color": "^3.2.1",
    "countries-list": "^2.6.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "file-type": "^14.7.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "hermes-engine": "^0.10.0",
    "rn-tourguide": "^3.4.1",
    "humanize-string": "^2.1.0",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^6.8.0",
    "i18next": "^21.9.2",
    "i18next-v4-format-converter": "^1.0.3",
    "iban": "0.0.14",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.1",
    "jest-date-mock": "^1.0.8",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.13",
    "lodash.flatmapdeep": "^4.10.0",
    "lodash.range": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash.truncate": "^4.4.2",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "no-case": "^3.0.4",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "ordinal": "^1.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "ramda": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
    "react-native": "^0.71.0",
    "react-native-adjust": "^4.35.1",
    "react-native-appboy-sdk": "^1.41.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-branch": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "7.1.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-copilot": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0",
    "react-native-drop-shadow": "^0.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.1",
    "react-native-input-scroll-view": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.1.8",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.17.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.22",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-share": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.2.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-version-info": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-zendesk-chat": "^0.4.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "realm": "11.5.1",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "reselect": "^4.1.6",
    "round-half-even": "^1.3.0",
    "round-to": "^6.0.0",
    "simple-credit-card-input": "^0.4.2",
    "simple-pincode-input": "^1.1.2",
    "snakecase-keys": "^5.4.2",
    "title-case": "^3.0.3",
    "url-parse": "^1.5.10",
    "use-deep-compare": "^1.1.0",
    "v8-android-jit-nointl": "^9.93.0",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.8",
    "yup": "^0.28.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.22",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "5.3.19",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.1.2",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^3.3.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-remove-test-ids": "^1.1.0",
    "detox": "^20.1.3",
    "detox-recorder": "^1.0.151",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": ">=7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
```

I searched for it and found these articles but none of them solve the issue for me. I feel like there might be some mismatch for between the configs, but I am not able to point out what.

[React-Native debugging: Failed to print error: Requiring module .... threw an exception: Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376641/react-native-debugging-failed-to-print-error-requiring-module-threw-an-ex)
[fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set when running jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749271/fbbatchedbridgeconfig-is-not-set-when-running-jest-tests).

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated